# Add custom date box in shopping cart in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I found an article [Magento – Add custom comment box to each product in Cart](http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/magento-add-comment-box-to-each-product-in-cart/), which says to do in accordance with the article is add a comment, I add the date, I succeeded.

Sidebar file is located here:

```
app/design/frontend/default/f001/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml
```

I have added the following code:

```
<script>
    function submitForm(){  

        var form = document.getElementById("form1");  
        form.submit();

        window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>"; 
        //window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart');?>";
    }  
</script>
<form id="form1" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button" onclick="submitForm()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
    <input type="text" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][wdate]" id="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][wdate]" value="<?php echo date("Y/m/d"); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" class="button btn-update" />

</form>
```

I want "My Cart" on the siebar as the same can be updated.But I have some problems in "My Cart", "My Cart" on the sidebar and Shopping cart in one page as if there is a conflict.Maybe used the same `<input>` name.Not together "My Cart" on the sidebar seems not working.Can’t update in database.How to fix it?